# Microsoft TFS SDK gradle

Tags: gradle, tfs-sdk

I would like to include the Microsoft TFS SDK jar into gradle build
I tried multiple example based on different blogs

In my project dependency I have tried below dependency:

1. `compile "com.microsoft.tfs:sdk:14.0.2"`
2. `compile "com.microsoft.tfs:tfssdk:14.0.2"`
3. `compile "com.microsoft.tfs:tsf-sdk:14.0.2"`

But non of them are working.
Please let me know if we have any support for TFS SDK jar in gradle.

Comment: What is not working, what's the problem?

Comment: I am getting com.microsoft.tfs:tsf-sdk:14.0.2 jar not found.

Comment: What repositories did you define?

Comment: url 'http://repo.spring.io/plugins-release'
    maven { url "http://repository.pentaho.org/content/groups/omni" }

I am using below two repository

Comment: In both repos you mentioned there's no such artifact.

Comment: can u plz tell me which repository we can use?

Comment: Sorry, you need to find it on your own.

Comment: Ok.Thanks for the comments